# Solving an Itô Integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Can someone please show me how to solve this Itô Integral?

$$\begin{align}\int_{1}^{t}\frac{dB_s}{B_s^2 + B_s^4}  && \end{align} $$

Comment: Start by taking $\int_{B_1}^{B_t} \frac{ds}{s^2+s^4}$. Then use Ito's formula on this quantity. Part of the result will be what you want, part of it won't. Figure out how to deal with the part that won't work. (This is the same strategy as you have probably already used to prove $\int_0^t B_s dB_s = \frac{B_t^2-t}{2}$.)

Comment: Hello @Ian, I am not sure I completely follow. Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: Start by actually doing what I said: compute $\int_{B_1}^{B_t} \frac{ds}{s^2+s^4}$ (this is just ordinary calculus) and use Ito's formula to compute the differential of this process. Put this in your question as a first attempt.

Comment: What does "solve an Itô integral" actually means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x}-\tan^{-1}x$. we have
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{x^2+x^4}$$
and
$$f''(x)=-\frac{2x+4x^3}{(x^2+x^4)^2}$$
By application of Ito's lemma we have
$$f(B_t)=f(B_1)+\int_{1}^{t}f'(B_s)dB_s+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{t}f''(B_s)ds$$
therefore
$$-\left(\frac{1}{B_t}+\tan^{-1}(B_t)\right)=-\left(\frac{1}{B_1}+\tan^{-1}(B_1)\right)+\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{B_s^2+B_s^4}dB_s-\int_{0}^{t}\frac{B_s+2B_s^3}{(B_s^2+B_s^4)^2}ds$$
In other words
$$\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{B_s^2+B_s^4}dB_s=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{B_s+2B_s^3}{(B_s^2+B_s^4)^2}ds-\left(\frac{1}{B_t}+\tan^{-1}(B_t)\right)+\left(\frac{1}{B_1}+\tan^{-1}(B_1)\right)$$

Comment: I'm not so sure that result is actually any better. (I realize this is the approach I suggested in my comments.)

Comment: you have said $\int_{B_1}^{B_t}\frac{1}{s^2+s^4}ds$

Comment: @Ian Are you sure this is the same as the approach you suggested?  Behrouz found a function $f$ such that an application of Ito's formula gave him the integral in question as a term, and then he solved for that integral.  I'm not completely sure, but I think the approach you suggested is a little different.

Comment: @user46944 It's essentially the same: $\int \frac{1}{s^2+s^4} ds = -1/s-\arctan(s)$, by the calculation that was given. Substitute in the limits that I suggested and you get the first two terms of Behrouz's Ito formula for $f(B_t)$. The limits that I suggested give $f(B_t)-f(B_1)$, which is a sum of the remaining two terms. One of the terms is what you want. The only difference between these approaches is that my suggestion tells you how to come up with $f$.

Comment: @Ian Given my very limited knowledge, I feel like Behrouz's final answer is the best we can do as far as 'computing" the Ito integral.  Do you think that's right?